# how to get javascript code too with the actual source with Html Agility Pack

Tags: javascript, c#, parsing, xpath, html-agility-pack

i am getting source of a website using Html Agility pack which is different than the code when i inspect with firebug.i have searched many things but still not getting clear of what i should do.Source is different than the code when i inspect please tell me how to get javascript code too with that Html. Even when i disable javascript in my browser i still cannot get the Javascript code along the source. i am using

```
string url="";
HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
                WebClient client = new WebClient();
                html = client.DownloadString(url);
                doc.LoadHtml(html);
```

to get source tell me if i should need a request and response method to get JS code too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To expand on [@alecxe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/771848/alecxe) answer, you can use Selenium* to load your target page like a real browser would do, and then pass the result to HtmlAgilityPack for further processing :

```
using OpenQA.Selenium;

.....

IWebDriver driver = new PhantomJS.PhantomJSDriver();
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(url);
HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(driver.PageSource);
```

alternatively, you can just run your query (XPath or CSS selector) using Selenium directly, for example :

```
var result = driver.FindElements(By.XPath("your query"));

//print HTML of the returned elements
foreach (var item in result)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item.GetAttribute("outerHTML"));
}
```

*) Need to download Selenium first, as well as the driver i.e PhantomJS, Firefox, etc. Selenium can be installed to your project easily from [NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Selenium.WebDriver).

Comment: Thanks a lot i have added selenium and phantomJS in my project now hope so it will work

Comment: i used that, it is working fine giving me extra code too but still not giving me that li inside an ol in a div which i want, i can see that div only when i inspect that through firebug with firefox, or give me suggestion what should i do

Answer (score 1):

For that you would need a real browser. Consider automating a browser (which can be headless - see [`PhantomJS`](http://phantomjs.org/)) with the help of [`selenium`](http://www.seleniumhq.org/download/).

See also:

- [Running Scripts in HtmlAgilityPack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11393075/running-scripts-in-htmlagilitypack)