# Scraping web site that runs javascript with C#

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, selenium, html-agility-pack

I am scraping web sites with HtmlAgilityPack but some websites run javascript after page load. So HtmlAgility does not help at this point. I have tried selenium web driver and NHtmlUnit and PhantomJS. But they are too slow for my task.

I also tried web browser but for asp.net it is slow and not a good solution for me. Also it does work for a few days after that that site has gived an error: "Javascript must be enabled"

So what do you suggest for me to do scrape those web sites fast enough?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Running Scripts in HtmlAgilityPack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11393075/running-scripts-in-htmlagilitypack)

Comment: @mjwills I edited my answer. I tried web browser but I am coding asp.net webform. So it is a little bit weird for me. Also it works for me for a few days but after those web sites give an error &amp;quot;Javascript must be enabled&amp;quot;