# Excecute script with HtmlAgilityPack

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

I'm using HtmlAgilityPack (with C#) to scrape a site. I'm having some luck, but having trouble getting the various colour images.

The page in question has a colour dropdown control, and when a colour is selected, a different image is displayed in the page.

The block of html code that does this is below (I have changed some identifying aspects of it):

```
<ul class="class1"><label class="class2" for="123456_0">Colour</label><div id="123456_0"><select id="123456_Input_0" onchange="updatePanel(0,'123456', true)"><option value="-1">Please select</option><option value="Colour:Green">Green</option><option value="Colour:Navy">Navy</option><option value="Colour:Orange">Orange</option><option value="Colour:White">White</option></select></div><label class="class2" for="123456_1">Size</label><div id="123456_1">Please select the Colour</div><input id="id1" value="123456" type="hidden" /><input id="id2" value="1" type="hidden" />
```

I suspect the important bits are:

- The onchange bit: onchange="updatePanel(0,'123456', true)"
- The option values: "Colour:Orange", "Colour:White", etc.

But I'm not quite sure what to do with them. Is this updatePanel a java script? If so, how do I execute it with HtmlAgilityPack?

Thanks.

Comment: Read this => https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11393075/running-scripts-in-htmlagilitypack

Comment: If that duplicate not enough - "C# scrape dynamic website" is search query to use so you can add what you've tried and how it did not work (so question can be re-opened if needed)