# HtmlAgilityPack - How to get the Value from the tag <div> into aspx.cs

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net, html-agility-pack

I have a task to do. I need to get the value from the tag into c#. I need to display the value into Label
This here is my HTML code:

```
<div size="10" id="para1"></div>  <p></p><asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="" Font-Size="XX-Large"></asp:Label><p></p><asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text="" Font-Size="XX-Large"></asp:Label>

<script>
document.getElementById("para1").innerHTML = formatAMPM();

    function formatAMPM() {
        var d = new Date(),

            days = ['sonday', 'monday', 'tuesday', 'Mittwoch', 'Donnerstag', 'Freitag', 'Samstag'];
        return days[d.getDay()];
    }</script>
```

from code behind i use this here to get the value but it does not work:

```
HtmlDocument page = new HtmlWeb().Load(@"D:\Downloads\wichtig\try\WebApplication1-Kopie-Kopie\MeineWebseite\löschen\WebForm2.aspx");
        var title = page.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//div[@id='para1']");
        Label3.Text = title.ToString();
```

I only know how to get the tag by Id. This is how it works

```
 document2.Load(@"D:\Downloads\wichtig\try\WebApplication1-Kopie-Kopie\MeineWebseite\löschen\WebForm2.aspx");

        string tag = document2.GetElementbyId("para1").Name;
        Label2.Text = tag;
```

That is how it works but I want Label3 should display the current date like

```
<div>id="para1</div>
```

it does.This here is the result
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wes2a.png)

Comment: what are you trying to get from the div? whats the value supposed to be for `Label3.Text` ?

Comment: I want Label3 should display the value of para1. It should display the current day. Today It should show Freitag. It means friday

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Running Scripts in HtmlAgilityPack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11393075/running-scripts-in-htmlagilitypack)

Comment: You cant execute scripts to find the values... its the browser that executes the scripts and updates the page.

Comment: Is there no way how solve it. I can only get the tag by Id

Comment: the date value is not part of the HTML for Html-Agility-Pack to scrape. It has not been evaluated and thus cant be scraped like how you are thinking. In your example, `div[@id='para1']` has no value or anything in it.

Comment: Thanks for your help but I dont understand "Running Scripts in HtmlAgilityPack " what its about

Comment: @Opijkkk Your browser runs JavaScript code.  HTMLAgilityPack does not.  If JavaScript code manipulates that div in any way, HTMLAgilityPack will not see it, as that manipulation will not have occurred there.

Comment: Thanks for your help. What would you recommend me to do

Comment: @Opijkkk Read the question/answer linked above by Jawad.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `InnerText` property:

```
var title = page.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//div[@id='para1']");
Label3.Text = title.InnerText;
```

Comment: There is no text in `title.InnerText`.. its blank.