# Triggering <select>'s option in c#

Tags: html-agility-pack

I m using html agility pack for crawling and getting some data, and there is a select dropdown on the webpage that I m using. I m able to parse the options and values as nodes. However I need to trigger that select option, because on the select option there is a js code which changes the data according to that option. It doesnt direct me on another page, but render the page and changes the data. How can I trigger each option in that select element and parse new data by using html agility pack?

Comment: You can't.  HtmlAgilityPack is an HTML parser; it is not a Javascript engine.  See [Running Scripts in HtmlAgilityPack](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11393075/10263).

Comment: At the end, I tried selenium web driver to trigger select options and get the data via HtmlAgilityPack and it worked!