# Cannot load InnerHTML from amazon music

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

Why I can't load the full inner html of the amazon music playlist like this: https://music.amazon.com/playlists/B0822YKQNT
My code works fine with spotify, but not with amazon music

```
HtmlWeb web = new HtmlWeb();
HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc = web.Load("https://open.spotify.com/playlist/37i9dQZF1E363OfvzqQxl0");
```

Comment: Need more details, what exactly happens? Error? Define "Can't load".

Comment: The inner html that Im receiving on doc = web.Load("https://open.spotify.com/playlist/37i9dQZF1E363OfvzqQxl0");
isn't full, it only contatins a small amount of info

Comment: That is a spotify link, is it Amazon or Spotify that doesnt work? Your Amazon link requires authentication, how are you authenticating?

Comment: yeah, sorry, amazon link isn't working as i expected, cause I forgot that I was logged in, and I have to work this out.

Comment: Actually it is not asking me to log in, i think i just have to make a pause for scripts to load, before loading the content, how can i achieve that

Comment: Agility pack no way to run scripts... See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11393075/running-scripts-in-htmlagilitypack#:~:text=Html%20Agility%20Pack%20is%20an,complete%20%22headless%22%20web%20browser.