# Include jQuery in Javascript file that won't be run inside webpage

Tags: javascript, jquery, jurassic

I am using Javascript to create a standalone script that will be invoked by a C#.NET application. It will not run within a browser, instead it will use the Jurassic engine.

I want to be able to use jQuery in this script. I normally reference jQuery using HTML `<script>` tags, but how do you include the jQuery file in a standalone Javascript file?

I am thinking of PHP's `include()` function.

Comment: Look at this example where he adds javascript libraries to Jurassic script engine. Its just so add strings before your script code. http://frederictorres.blogspot.se/2013/11/scripting-c-application-with-javascript.html  . But I am not sure you can add jQuery. It is for DOM selecting and Jurassic do not give you the DOM like a webbrowser. See: http://stackoverflow.com/q/10886161/648076  " I have looked at .Net javascript engines such as Jurassic and Jint, but neither support loading a DOM, and so therefore can't do what I need."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just put a minified Version in top of your standalone js-file !

it should be as simple as that