# How do I scrape web content from secure sites after authenticating?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, web-scraping

I'm looking to scrape details from web sites by posting form values and getting a response page to parse in return, but having challenges with certain situations.

For non-financial sites like Slashdot.org, the below code works fine, even after logging in and scraping my own account details as a test.

But with financial sites, the same code returns a response page with verbiage like, "For your security, you must enable JavaScript to sign on to your account" and none of my financial details that I would expect to see like the account balances. Note that the response status code of "OK" (200) in this scenario doesn't indicate obvious errors. I want to build a personal "Mint.com"-type site but it's become quite challenging in this regard.

Assuming there are more robust security controls in financial sites, what can I do with the following code snippet to better handle these scenarios?

```
// I call this method to do the heavy lifting
public async Task<string> GetHttpResponseMessage(string url, IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, string>> values)
{
    var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(values);            
    var response = await httpClient.PostAsync(url, content);
    var responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    return responseString;
}
```

Comment: See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11393075/running-scripts-in-htmlagilitypack) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10886161/load-a-dom-and-execute-javascript-server-side-with-net/10886733#10886733)  for information on how to run page scripts. You are going to need a script engine, such as the one in your browser, so the accepted answer suggests using a WebBrowser control.

Comment: I find using multiple webpages work very well in cases like this.  I keep one web page on the main pages and then use second webpage to scrape the children.  You can always make the main page invisible when going to the children.

Comment: Thanks, John Wu, these seem to be more what I am looking for.